avoid black screen between fbi calls
I want to run fbi calls asynchronously on my raspberrypi zero.
There is an other similar question but his setup is not asynchronous.
When I call sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 /path/to/some/file.png and then sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 /path/to/some/file2.png there is a delay where the screen goes black.
How do I avoid this?
